# prettyPhoto doesn't work with ASP.NET URL routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, prettyphoto, asp.net-routing

I'm using prettyPhoto in my asp.net project. I have some issue.
When i use url routing in my project, prettyPhoto doesn't work. Image opening on _self target (It doesn't seem as popup)
If i don't use routing it's working fine.

Do you have any idea? You can see my sample code below.

Global.asax

```
 void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("Details","Details/{Detail}/{Title}","~/Detail.aspx");               
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Page Url

```
http://example.com/Details/SampleDetail/SampleTitle
```

When the cursor on my image, url seems as

```
 example.com/images/image1.jpg`
```

It's working

```
<a href='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>'  rel="prettyPhoto[myImageGroupName]" title="Some Text"/>
```

It doesn't work

```
<a href='<%# Page.ResolveUrl(Eval("ImageUrl").ToString()) %>'  rel="prettyPhoto[myImageGroupName]" title="Some Text"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My script tags were like below.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So scripts (because of url routing) were searched by below directory

```
/example.com/Details/SampleDetail/SampleTitle/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js ...
```

Scripts must be as follows:

```
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js") %>'></script>
 <script src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```